# SendMessage with array paramter in unity webgl

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Unity SendMessage can only pass one parameter and it can be an array. So i am calling my sendMessage for javascript and calling C# method(acutally webgl method)

```
var arr = [x,y,z];
gameInstance.SendMessage("Cube","SetGameObjectPosition",arr);
```

but getting this error

> Invoking error handler due to
>
> Uncaught 2,2,2 is does not have a type which is supported by
>   SendMessage. [Violation] 'click' handler took 8994ms
>   blob:http://localhost/1ff50200-cb3a-4367-ab45-f02e9734fac2:2 Uncaught
>   2,2,2 is does not have a type which is supported by SendMessage.
>
> SendMessage @
>   blob:http://localhost/1ff50200-cb3a-4367-ab45-f02e9734fac2:2
>
> SendMessage @ UnityLoader.js:4
>
> SetObjectPosition @ (index):44
>
> onclick @ (index):65 (index):65
>
> [Violation] 'click' handler took 9000ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SendMessage Docu](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

> `SendMessage(objectName, methodName, value);`
>
> Where `objectName` is the name of an object in your scene; `methodName` is the name of a method in the script, currently attached to that object; **`value` can be a string, a number, or can be empty.**

-> no it can not be an array

---

But it seems you want to pass on a position so as a workaround you could pass in the string like "2,2,2" and use

```c#
string[] numberStrings = ("2,2,2").Split(",");
float x = float.TryParse(numberStrings[0], out x) ? x : 0;
float y = float.TryParse(numberStrings[1], out y) ? y : 0;
float z = float.TryParse(numberStrings[2], out z) ? z : 0;
```

or something like that

Comment: I'd send it as JSON just for the sake of standard.

Comment: @Everts sounds a bit overkill to me for just passing 3 floats without any furthor structure but sure why not ^^ would need more bandwith though ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, silly me i was mixing the things and thinking that third value can be an array as well. Anyway thanks for correction. I am already doign concatenation and spliting the string but searching for other better way. For this reason trying Shingo solution. Seems much clear and better.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan that's probably true, but he didn't actually answer the question why it is not working ;)

Comment: @derHugo i wish to accept Shingo answer but your made a correct point.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a json string:

```
var pos = {x:1,y:2,z:3};
gameInstance.SendMessage("Cube","SetGameObjectPosition", JSON.stringify(pos));
```

In unity:

```
void SetGameObjectPosition(string data)
{
    var position = JsonUtility.FromJson<Vector3>(data);
}
```